# What is the best way to process 200MB payload (Request) size in Rest API or Azure Function app

Tags: azure-functions, rabbitmq, kafka-consumer-api, azure-webjobs

I Have a problem with rest payload size. Now I am using azure functions, but it is not allowing more than 100MB request size. Is there any way to process huge payload sizes in azure functions or .net Core Rest API's. Suggest any alternative way to process huge payload of sizes mote than 200MB.

I tried with code optimizing and azure durable functions with webhooks. But as limitations of azure functions it can accept up to 100MB payload size. need a suggestions or approach to solve this kind of huge payload processing.

Comment: If you've confirmed that azure functions has a hard limit, have you considered using something else?

Comment: yes I need to use some other alternative to azure functions

Comment: Ok, is this question resolved then?

Comment: no Evert searching for other alternatives